# jquery: custom select box?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

hey guys,
i'm trying to do a rather simple select box by myself.

```
<div class="select">
    <ul>
        <li class="option darr">Dropdown one</li>
        <li class="option">Dropdown two</li>
        <li class="option">Dropdown three</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded only the first li-item is set to display:block. When I click on the first one, all options should be displayed.

So far so good...

```
/*select box*/
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
    $('.select ul li.option').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

However now I'm stuck. When I click e.g. on the second option this one should have the .darr class applied and the the dropdown should collapse again with the second option visible. You know what I mean!

Any idea how to solve that? With toggle()?

Here is a fiddle, so you see what I mean! http://jsfiddle.net/WFTvq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().toggle().removeClass('darr');
        $(this).addClass('darr');
    });
```

can you check this?

Comment: thank you perfect. Is there any chance to collapse the selectbox when nothing get's selected? http://jsfiddle.net/WFTvq/2/ If I click on the selectbox once all options are shown - when I don't select one of the options and click anywhere on the rest of the screen, the selectbox does not automatically collapse. any chance to implement that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good way to do it ! ^^ I just made it few seconds ago ;)

**HTML**

```
<div class="styledSelect">
                <span class="styledSelectValue"></span>
                <select name="type">
                    <option value="">Par type de propriété</option>
                    <option value="choix2">choix2</option>
                    <option value="choix3">choix3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.styledSelect{/*your css for the background image... it will be the body of your select*/}
.styledSelect select{/*your css with opacity:0;*/}
.styledSelectValue{/*the css of the received value*/}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.styledSelect').each(function(){
            selectValue = $(this).children("select").val();
            if(selectValue == ""){selectValue = $(this).children("select").children("option:eq(0)").text();}
            $(this).children(".styledSelectValue").text(selectValue);
        });
        $('.styledSelect select').change(function(){
            selectValue = $(this).val();
            if(selectValue == ""){selectValue = $(this).children("option:eq(0)").text();}
            $(this).parent(".styledSelect").children(".styledSelectValue").text(selectValue);
        });
```

It's the best way i found ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
$('.select ul li.option').fadeIn('fast');
$('.select ul li.darr').removeClass('darr');
$(this).addClass('darr');});
```

Comment: yeah, that applies the class, but how do I hide all other options on click. It should toggle. If only one option is visible and I click all options should be displayed. When I click now on a different option the dropdown should collapse again and only the selected option should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and jQuery:

CSS:

```
.select {
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li.option {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none; /* <- hides the li elements of class 'option' */
}

ul:hover li.option {
    display: block; /* <- shows all options on ul:hover */
}

li.option.darr {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('li.option').click(
    function(){
        $('.darr').removeClass('darr');
        $(this).addClass('darr');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BJcnY/).